# Regexp. Set substring length

Tags: c#, regex

I have next string `"USA_NewYork_YYYYMMDD.txt"`

I ought to set in my pattern `YYYYMMDD` length

I use next pattern `@"^USA_NewYork_+[\d{8}$]+.txt$"`

but it failes because of next files also are searched

```
USA_NewYork_2011098.txt
USA_NewYork_201109081.txt
```

What is wrong in my pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You want this pattern:

```
@"^USA_NewYork_\d{8}\.txt$"
```

The way you have it now, it matches a string that starts with `USA_NewYork`, then one or more `_`s, then one or more characters from the collection `any digit`, `{`, (`8` is already in the "any digit" class), `}` or `$`, then one single character (anything except newlines), and finally `txt`.

`[abc]` is a character class, meaning "one character, either an `a`, a `b` or a `c`".

I suggest you read a [basic regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info), especially the section on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: His second example has 9 digits, not 8.

Comment: I need 8 length string. I showed wrong examples. Tim thanks! Works!

Comment: Yes, and I think he doesn't want it to be matched (neither the first one with 7 digits), he wants exactly 8 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `@"^USA_NewYork_+\d{8}\.txt$` . This will work if you want to match just 8 digits, not any more not any  less.